# How to retrieve data form multi tables according to condition in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables in my database

```
courses                                  degree_plan
--------------------                   ------------------------                
course     course_no                    major        course_no 
--------------------                   ------------------------
CHEM101        1                        COE               1
Math101        2                        SWE               1
                                        SWE               2

student                                  equal
-------------------------------     ---------------------------------------- 
course_no      ID       grade        course_no   course    equivalent    ID
-------------------------------     ----------------------------------------
1              5544      A            1        CHEM101    chemistry 1   5544 
1              5533      A            2        Math101   mathematics 1  5533
2              5533      B
```

I wrote this query

```
SELECT * FROM courses LEFT JOIN equal ON equal.course_no=courses.course_no 
LEFT JOIN degree_plan ON degree_plan.course_no =courses.course_no 
LEFT JOIN student ON courses.course_no= student.course_no 
AND student.id=5533 WHERE degree_plan.major='SWE';
```

when I run this query it retrieve all rows in equal table I do not want that because I want to retrieve from equal table according to id of student that written in the query .

How I can run the query in order to retrieve from equal table according to id without removing left join?

Comment: Move your `WHERE` clause condition to your `ON` condition for the `LEFT JOIN` to `degree_plan`.  You're converting the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` by including it in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are wanting "All rows in equal table" is meaningless. Can you, using your sample data here, show your desired results?

Comment: the output will be from all equal table   I need only row for student who id is 5533 in equal table

Comment: Please show the sample output and the desired output, rather than describing them.

Answer (score 0):

I think for the student you need an left  join and (condition)

```
    SELECT * FROM courses LEFT JOIN equal ON equal.course_no=courses.course_no 
    LEFT JOIN degree_plan ON degree_plan.course_no =courses.course_no 
    LEFT JOIN student ON ( courses.course_no= student.course_no 
        AND student.id=5533 ) 
    WHERE degree_plan.major='SWE';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM courses LEFT JOIN equal ON equal.course_no=courses.course_no 
LEFT JOIN degree_plan ON degree_plan.course_no =courses.course_no 
LEFT JOIN student ON courses.course_no= student.course_no 
 WHERE degree_plan.major='SWE' AND equal.id=5533;
```

You just need to move `AND equal.id=5533` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The OP's question specifically says *without removing the `LEFT JOIN`* - this solution would convert both the `degree_plan` and `student` `LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: Pls edit your question on the output you want, because i'm not sure i have understood what you want. And I have edited my answer.